# Keywords not showing up using journal template

Tags: article, abstract, elsarticle, keywords

So I am submitting a journal article to Elsevier, and using their [template](http://cdn.elsevier.com/promis_misc/PRLetters-28012014.zip). However, I am unable to get keywords to work. I am replacing the dummy words with mine, but none of it is showing up. Can you suggest any solution? Its not even throwing errors, the keyword1 etc is just not showing up! Thanks.

```
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\MSC 41A05\sep 41A10\sep 65D05\sep 65D17
\KWD Keyword1\sep Keyword2\sep Keyword3

%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%\linenumbers

%% main text
\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: It is only set when you add `\articleinfobox` somewhere after you've defined everything. What does the template say about including these as part of your submission?

Comment: I don't quite get you, can you please have a quick look here and suggest? http://cdn.elsevier.com/promis_misc/PRLetters-28012014.zip

Comment: I did look at that in order to find `\articleinfobox`. Insert `\articleinfobox` just after `\end{keyword}` and you'll see an information box printed about your article - this includes the keywords. If this is a template from a publisher and they don't include the keywords by default, then you shouldn't worry about it (IMO). Hence my question: "What does the template say about including these as part of your submission?"

Comment: thanks! got it.. it does show up keywords in a separate page above abstract. And they say "Immediately after the abstract, provide a maximum of 6 keywords, using American spelling and avoiding general and plural terms and multiple concepts (avoid, for example, 'and', 'of'). Be sparing with abbreviations: only abbreviations firmly established in the field may be eligible. These keywords will be used for indexing purposes."

Comment: There is a "graphical" abstract and then a "regular" abstract. The keywords (or `\articleinfobox`) seem to be shown between these. However, there is no mention of you actually having to *print* (or set) these keywords. If you define them, they will probably use them, in whichever way it seems fit.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Werner Wanna sum up your comments in a quick answer?

Answer (score 6):

[Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) gave some helpful advice in the comments:

Insert `\articleinfobox` just after `\end{keyword}` and you'll see an information box printed about your article - this includes the keywords. If this is a template from a publisher and they don't include the keywords by default, then you shouldn't worry about it (IMO).

There is a "graphical" abstract and then a "regular" abstract. The keywords (or `\articleinfobox`) seem to be shown between these. However, there is no mention of you actually having to print (or set) these keywords. If you define them, they will probably use them, in whichever way it seems fit.

Comment: That was not true in my experience. I am currently trying to make those keywords visible on my compiled pdf, since it is requested by the technical reiviewer. Here is the request:

**1.The Keywords should be included beneath the abstract in title page of manuscript.**