# Why are the article keywords not visible when using elsarticle class?

Tags: elsarticle, keywords

I'm preparing a manuscript using Elsevier provided [latex template](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/computer-vision-and-image-understanding/1077-3142/guide-for-authors).

I want to have final view like this published paper, as article info is present besides abstract [image: Elsevier published paper view]
Using below elsevier provided template's latex code

```
\documentclass[times,referee,twocolumn,final,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ycviu}
\usepackage{framed,multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{newcolor}{rgb}{.8,.349,.1}


\journal{Computer Vision and Image Understanding}

\begin{document}

\ifpreprint
  \setcounter{page}{1}
\else
  \setcounter{page}{1}
\fi

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Type the title of your paper, only capitalize first
word and proper nouns}

\author[1]{Fname \snm{Sname}} 

\received{1 May 2013}
\finalform{10 May 2013}
\accepted{13 May 2013}
\availableonline{15 May 2013}
\communicated{S. Sarkar}


\begin{abstract}
Type your abstract here....
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\MSC 41A05\sep 41A10\sep 65D05\sep 65D17
\KWD Keyword1\sep Keyword2\sep Keyword3

%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
```

I'm getting below view 
[image]
Here keywords are not visible in its output pdf file. I tried already provided solutions on this website i.e. [put keywords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257400/how-do-i-put-keywords-into-abstract-in-elsarticle?rq=1) , [keywords not showing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188454/keywords-not-showing-up-using-journal-template) and [keywords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69137/program-package-extra-or-forgotten-endgroup) but no one is working as required.

Comment: Is visible in the draft or default view (loading elsaricle class without any options)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `ycviu` LaTeX package does not appear to be distributed with TeXLive. Is it available online somewhere?

Comment: @Mico Yes on this [link]{https://www.elsevier.com/journals/computer-vision-and-image-understanding/1077-3142/guide-for-authors} uder template heading

Comment: If you look at the PDF files coming with the template, they show no keyword even if they're in the source TeX files. I guess the journal doesn't want them or, maybe, they'll be added in the product version.

Comment: @Mico due to ycviu.sty file, keywords and article info are not visible. but I have to use this package because it has other functionalities too.

Comment: @hesham still not visible in draft view

Comment: @memuna The code in your MWE is not complete, it cannot be compiled. Moreover, the output view that you post is not the result of that code.

Comment: One more advice, don't get yourself too busy by reproducing an exact replica of the journal final production, because a lot of features are proprietary of the house, that they don't release publicly. So don't waste your time, keep things simple and focus on the contents of your paper.

Answer (score 2):

The template asks you to use the journal style by doing `\usepackage{ycviu}`.

In this package I find the definition of the `keyword` environment as

```latex
% Keyword
\def\keyword{%
  \def\sep{\newline}%
  \def\MSC{\@ifnextchar[{\@MSC}{\@MSC[2000]}}%
  \def\@MSC[##1]{\leavevmode\hbox {\it ##1~MSC:}\newline}%
  \def\JEL{\newline\leavevmode\hbox {\it JEL:\space}}%
  \def\KWD{%
   \vspace*{10pt}\newline
   \leavevmode\hbox {\it Keywords:}\newline}%
  \global\setbox\keybox=\hbox\bgroup\hsize=.3\textwidth%
  \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont%
  \parskip\z@%
  \noindent%
  \ignorespaces}
\def\endkeyword{\egroup}
```

The environment typesets its contents and saves the result in the box named `\keybox`. The only other place where `\keybox` appears is in the definition of `\articleinfobox`

```latex
\def\articleinfobox{
    \parbox[t]{.35\textwidth}{%
    \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont%
    [...irrelevant code here...]
    \hrule
    \vspace*{1pc}
    \unhbox\keybox}
}
```

However, `\articleinfobox` appears *nowhere else*.

This just means that the copy editors of the journal have a *different* version of `ycviu` they use for the final version.

What you're provided with is a version of the package that's suitable for submissions to the journal and to produce the copy for the referees. Just don't worry. You *can't* replicate the final product yourself and I see good reasons for this: you won't be able to emulate the final form of the article pretending it has been published.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's what I got after keeping only the basic commands (with a little modification) for your posted MWE. Actually, the keywords were printed fine, with and without your options of the `elsarticle` class.

[image]

The simple code I used was

```
\documentclass[times,referee,twocolumn,final,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for printing dummy text
%
\journal{Computer Vision and Image Understanding}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{frontmatter}
%
\title{Type the title of your paper, only capitalize first word and proper nouns}
\author{Fname Sname}
%
\begin{abstract}
    Type your abstract here.... \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
%
\begin{keyword}
Keyword1 \sep Keyword2 \sep Keyword3 \sep Keyword4 \sep Keyword5 \sep Keyword6
\end{keyword}
%
\end{frontmatter}
%
\section{Introduction}
    This is the introduction. \lipsum[2]
%
\section{Results}
This is the results. \lipsum[2]
%
\section{Conclusion}
This is the conclusion. \lipsum[2]
%
\end{document}
```

So you can start by adding and removing in that code the rest of your commands, and then recompile, until you get to know the reason of conflict with the keywords in your case.

Comment: @memuna Being busy indoors and distant everything, I couldn't get time to post that answer earlier!! In fact it's amazing how people here do find the time to answer so many questions, which is very helpful indeed.

Comment: The template that the OP has to use apparently suppresses the printing of the keywords.  If you remove `\usepackage{ycviu}` then the keywords appear, but that package is mandatory for the OP's submission.

Comment: The `\usepackage{ycviu}` cannot be loaded in my distribution (miktex, win10)!

Comment: You can download it from the link provided by the OP.